# Node.js + REST Architecture: Mid-Tier vs No Mid-Tier

Tags: node.js, rest, middleware, restful-architecture, n-tier-architecture

We are working on a large Node based ERP project and there is some internal debate as to where the bulk of the business rules should reside in a Node environment. Given that Node is single threaded (albeit non-blocking) it seems to make sense to put the business rules in a separate mid-tier ([Option #3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwekU.jpg)) for more effective load balancing as well as providing a more robust public REST API that exposes the business rules rather than a simple CRUD interface. However, it seems that mid-tiers have fallen out of favor recently. In a multi-threaded Java or .Net environment the case could be made to put the business rules behind one main REST API (Option #2). Or, the business rules could live in the web tier (Option #1), but the public REST API would simply provide CRUD without the business rules. This topic can get a bit 'intense' at times, but we are interested in any constructive suggestions and comments regarding the various options.

[Architectural Options (click here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwekU.jpg)

Comment: I am currently in the midst of this same discussion with our server architects and I came across [this article](http://www.thoughtworks.com/insights/blog/rest-api-design-resource-modeling).  In short, it's kind of a "both" answer - and the business ("transactional") tier cannot be created in a one-size-fits-all type of manner.  At the very least, your front end should not have to know about "hard" business logic.

Comment: Node.js complicates this discussion significantly because it's single threaded. I'm thinking that to achieve multitasking-like performance using Node.js with SOA that two separate Node based REST layers are required. One for CRUD and one for the business rules.

Comment: I have found that the single-threaded nature of node was not too much of an issue for multi-tasking.  Async coding requires a different way of thinking and "waiting" for tasks to finish before moving forward, but my experience is that it's still faster than "linear" multi-threaded languages.  If a certain task takes longer than a couple seconds, then you might resort to kicking off a task and then polling (or web-socket message posting) to see when the task is done.  Node (unlike other languages) makes this very easy.

Comment: Can you describe exactly what you mean by 'kick of a task'. Thx.

Comment: Specifically, can you 'kick off' tasks from within a Node process (not initiated directly from the UI or REST end-point)?

Comment: So we just built an app recently where a user requested an object.  If that object did not exist yet, we created a record in our database with an `processing` flag set to true.  We went ahead and sent a response to the front end with a status of `202` and the server proceeded with a ~5 second long process for creating the object for the first time.  When the front end received a `202`, it polled every ~1 second to see if the object was done.  Node servers can also have cron jobs if you want a non-user initiated process to kick off.